# How to use jQuery after downloading it using NuGet

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, nuget

I downloaded `jQuery` in `Visual Studio 2017` using `Install-Package bootstrap -Version 4.1.1` 
Now I have a dependency which includes jQuery 3.3.1, but when I move to my script file, I can´t access `jQuery` and I don't get `IntelliSense` for `jQuery` when I enter `$.` 
Is there some reference I must enter, in order to use `jQuery` in my script file?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) because it's too broad a topic to get a tutorial here.

Comment: And you will need to know how and where to include/reference the file in your scripts

Comment: @PeterSmith there is no folder where jQuery is saved in, what should I include?

Comment: If you are using .NET Core then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923853/how-to-use-jquery-in-asp-net-core) otherwise just Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use jQuery after downloading it using NuGet

You should use `Bower` or the `npm` (Node Package Manager) to add the JavaScript libraries instead of using NuGet. Because **the usage of NuGet for `css/javascript` libraries is discouraged**.

**However**, since [ASP.NET Core 2.0 and the End of Bower](https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower), so we **recommend** you to use `npm` (Node Package Manager) to manage `css/javascript` libraries.

To use the package `bootstrap` to the .net core project, you need to select your project and add a new file to the project root. While in the template manager (Add->New Item...), search for "npm Configuration file".

Then edit the file and add your dependency, i.e.

package.json (npm):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1"
  }
```

Note: For package.json (npm), once you save, the file will be downloaded in a directory named "node_modules`. This alone won't be enough, **as the required files need to be copied over to wwwroot folder**, where they can be accessed when the application runs.

For the detailed info, see [NPM, BOWER, NUGET, GULP – The Four Horsemen of ASP.NET CORE Apps](https://fiyazhasan.azurewebsites.net/npm-bower-nuget-gulp-the-four-horsemen-of-asp-net-core-apps/).

Comment: Is this still the recommended approach in 2024?